# C# declare variable into if statement

Tags: c#, variables, if-statement

i want to do something like this using C# :

```
if (i == 0)
{
 button a = new button();
}
else
{
 TextBlock a = new TextBlock();
}
mainpage.children.add(a);
```

But i get an error that

> Error 1   The name 'a' does not exist in the current context

Any ideas ?

thank you in advance !

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need a common base class that both `button` and `Textblock` derive from, and it needs to be declared outside of the `if` statement if it's to be accessed after the `if` is complete. `Control` maybe?

```
Control a;
if (i == 0)
{
 a = new button();
}
else
{
 a = new TextBlock();
}
mainpage.children.add(a);
```

Not knowing what specific control toolkit you're using (WPF maybe?) I can't advise further. But I'd look at the signature for `Add` to get a clue - what's the parameter declared as?

Comment: However, the question is more about [scopes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132(v=vs.71).aspx). Title: _"declare variable into if statement"_ exception: _"The name 'a' does not exist in the current context"_

Comment: @TimSchmelter That's splitting hairs, to be honest. This addresses that, perhaps in a roundabout way that directs the user to an alternative and thinking they're new to, but still.

Comment: @GrantThomas: Imho titles and questions are not so unimportant on SO, allthemore for future visitiors who are looking for an answer why they get this exception and why they cannot use a variable outside of an `if`. So one or two words about it or a link would have been helpful.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Precisely, you're right. With the knowledge now gained of the OPs actual problem, more properly framed, the title should be changed.

Answer (score 6):

Try declaring `a` outside of the scope of the if/else. Like this:

```
Control a;
if (i == 0)
{
  a = new button();
}
else
{
  a = new TextBlock();
}
mainpage.children.add(a);
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to declare your variable in parent scope and give it a common base class. The common base class for `System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock` and `System.Windows.Controls.Button` can be for example `System.Windows.UIElement` or `System.Windows.FrameworkElement`. So your code can look like this:

```
UIElement a;
if (i == 0)
{
    a = new Button();
}
else
{
    a = new TextBlock();
}
mainpage.children.add(a);
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a discussion about declaring and assigning variables inside a condition here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/11a423f9-9fa5-4cd3-8a77-4fda530fbc67

It seems it cannot be done in C#, even though you can in other languages